# Can equality of chromatic symmetric functions of two trees be checked in polynomial time?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

Stanley defined chromatic symmetric functions (CSF) in 1995 (Advances in Math) where he conjectured that trees can be distinguished by their CSF. However, tree isomorphism is decidable in P (polynomial time). So, if the conjecture is true then checking equality of CSF for trees is in P. Thus, being able to do it in P would provide evidence (although not definitive proof) that probably Stanley's conjecture is true. To my knowledge, there is an algorithm to do it in RP (randomised polynomial) in this preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07363v2. Thus, this shows that the problem is in NP (as RP is contained in NP).
Does anybody know if this problem has been looked at from a complexity perspective, and more specifically is the problem of checking equality of CSF of two trees in P?

Comment: Presumably known information about this problem would be in the paper you cited, and the papers that cite it.

Comment: So, the input is two trees, and the output is YES iff the two trees have the same CSF? And you ask if this can be done in polynomial time? So, if the trees are isomorphic, we're done since isomorphism can be checked quickly...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson, yes that is true and hence the next question will be what happens if the trees are not isomorphic and their CSF are the same. If Stanley's conjecture is true then there will no such trees and hence we are done. Thus, what I ask is a statement that will be implied by Stanley's conjecture but is a weaker statement and hence might be easier to prove.